# c# outline numbering

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop an algorithm in C# that can take an array list of URL's and output them in an outline numbered list.

As you can imagine I need some help. Does anyone have any suggestions on the logic to use to generate this list?

Example Output:

```
1   - http://www.example.com/aboutus
1.2 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page1
1.3 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page2
1.3.1   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page2/page3
1.3.1.1 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page2/page3/page4
1.3.2   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page5/page6
1.3.2.1 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page5/page7/page9
1.3.2.2 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page5/page8/page10

1.4 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page10
1.4.1   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page10/page11
1.4.2   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page10/page12

1.1.5   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page13

1.1.6   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page14
1.1.6.1 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page14/page15
1.1.6.2 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page14/page16
1.1.6.3 - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page14/page17
```

... and so on

Comment: hi, isn't there a glitch in 1.3.2 and 1.3.2.1? I'd call the second 1.3.3.1 instead - is that right?

Comment: Why this >> `1.1.5   - http://www.example.com/aboutus/page13`?. Why not it is `1.5`?

Comment: Is the list initially sorted in the order you want it numbered? Why is `http://www.example.com/aboutus/aboutus` not 1.1?

Comment: Ok, I gotta ask: what have you tried?

Comment: if i look at the sample, 1 is a substring in 1.2 and 1 in 1.3. May be using a simple logic on string.contains methods and via efficient searching algorithm you can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have to strip protocol and query string parameters, so +1 to the advise to use `System.URI` class to handle that.

As for the printing it in tree-shape - a direct approach is to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to keep association of child (key) to a parent (value).

Another way is to take advantage of `List<T>.Sort`, e.g. like this:

```
public static void Print(List<string> list)
{
    var path = new Stack<string>();
    var count = new Stack<int>();
    path.Push("");
    count.Push(0);

    list.Sort(new Comparison<string>(UrlComparison));

    foreach (var x in list)
    {
        while (!x.StartsWith(path.Peek())) { path.Pop(); count.Pop(); }
        count.Push(count.Pop() + 1);
        foreach(var n in count.Reverse()) Console.Write("{0}.", n);
        Console.WriteLine(" {0}", x);
        path.Push(x);
        count.Push(0);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `p.campbell` is right, a custom comparison is actually required here, which makes this implementation still pretty performant, but more bulky (`?:-abuse` warning):

```
public static int UrlComparison(string x, string y)
{
    if (x == null && y == null) return 0;
    if (x == null) return -1;
    if (y == null) return 1;
    for(int n = 0; n < Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length); n++)
    {
        char cx = x[n], cy = y[n];
        if(cx == cy) continue;
        return
            (cx == '/' || cx == '.' || cx == '?') ? -1 :
            (cy == '/' || cy == '.' || cy == '?') ? 1 :
            (cx > cy) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return (x.Length == y.Length) ? 0 : (x.Length > y.Length) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

PS: Just to put a disclaimer, I feel that Stacks logic is consize, but a bit more complex to understand. In a long-term project, I'd stick with a child-parent dictionary.

Comment: Excellent start! One nit: the sorting is current such that it [sorts "Page10" to just under "Page1"](http://i.imgur.com/5Vnzf.png)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the System.URI class. It should have some methods and properites that should be usefull, like the segments property that splilts the uri into its segmented parts (split by slash bascially). You could create a list of the segment arrays, sort the list, then simply iterate the list adjusting the numbers depending on wether the current list index segments match the previous list index segments.

Answer (score 2):

May be this [Generic Tree Collection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/treecollection2.aspx) will be helpful.

There are few Tree Collections on the [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com): [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/trees.aspx), [two](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/phSharpTree.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement some sort of tree collection to handle the order.  Because if you added a new link called http://www.example.com, that would become 1 instead of http://www.example.com/aboutus.

Then you can print the in-order traversal of the tree and it will be exceedingly simple.